Does rectifiability imply continuity?
I am trying to prove the following statement:

Let $\mathscr{L}(x)$ denote the length of $f$ on $[a,x]$. If $f$ is rectifiable on $[a,x]$ for every $x\in[a,b)$ and $$\lim_{x\to b^-} \mathscr{L}(x)=L$$ then $f$ is rectifiable on $[a,b]$ and $\mathscr{L}(b)=L$

in order to show that a semi-circle is rectifiable and its length is given by the improper integral $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$. I am able to do this if I assume that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, which is the case here, but it got me wondering if this statement was true in cases where $f$ is rectifiable but not continuous. Can a function be rectifiable on an interval without being continuous?
For context, I am using the following definition of rectifibiality of a function on a closed interval:

Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ and let $\ell(f,P)$ denote the length of the chord-polygonal inscribed in $f$ i.e. $$\ell (f,P):=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{[x_{k}-x_{k-1}]^{2}+[f(x_{k}-f(x_{k-1}))]^{2}}$$
If $\{\ell (f,P)|P \text{ is a partition of }[a,b]\}$ is bounded above, the curve is said to be rectifiable  and the length of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is defined as $$\mathscr{L}:=\sup \{\ell (f,P)|P \text{ is a partition of }[a,b]\} $$


What about $\chi_{[0,1]}+2\chi_{[1,2]}$ on $[0,2]$? Here $\chi_A(x)=1$ iff $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

@GhostAmarth apologies but I do not understand your notation. I am afraid I am only familiar with elementary calculus.

Using $\mathscr L(x)\le \lvert x-a\rvert+V_a^x(f)$, any discontinuous function that is [BV on $a,b)$ will do.

@VulgarMechanick Even easier what about $f\colon [0, 2]\to\mathbb R$ with $f(x)=0$ for $0\leq x < 1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $1\leq x\leq 2$?

@GhostAmarth Is this rectifiable? If so, is the length 2 or 3 (counting the vertical jump of the curve)?

Perhaps you are interested in the following: if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-} \mathcal{L}(x)=\mathcal{L},$ then $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exists.

@RyszardSzwarc Yes actually, that would be sufficient to prove the original claim that I wanted to prove. Could you advise me on how to go about proving your claim?

For $x<y$ consider partitions of $[a,y]$  such that $x$ is the penultimate point. Then taking the supremum over such partitions we get $$ \mathcal{L}(y)\ge \mathcal{L}(x)+\sqrt {(y-x)^2+[f(y)-f(x)]^2}\ge \mathcal{L}(x)+|f(y)-f(x)|$$ Let $x_n\nearrow b$ with $x_1=a.$ Then $$\mathcal{L}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty [ \mathcal{L}(x_k)- \mathcal{L}(x_{k-1})]\ge \sum_{k=2}^\infty|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|$$ Therefore the series $\sum_{k=2}^\infty[f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})]$ is convergent. Its $n$th partial sum is equal $f(x_n)-f(a).$ Therefore the limit $\lim_nf(x_n)$ exists. As the sequence $x_n$ was arbitrary the limit $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exists. The continuity of $f$ on $[a,b)$ was not essential. However if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b)$ then it can be extended to the continuous function on $[a,b]$ by setting $f(b)=\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x).$
